# oracle, set timezone from a table or database schema level

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, timestamp

We are currently migrating our database from Sybase to Oracle cloud v12. In the old server it was owned entirely by us so we could change the server timezone to UK time along with reflecting daylight savings. We are trying to implement the same change in the Oracle database but we cannot do the same fix as server will be shared with another team. Does anyone know a way to change the default time zone that systimestamp or to_timestamp_tz() uses?

The purpose of this is because we have team members around the world connecting to this database so we want a central default timezone.

We considered changing default SESSION parameters but this would only work for the individuals' local machines and not for functional users or servers running these scripts/queries.

I have tried looking for suitable NLS params but could not find any to do this.

From looking at V$TIMEZONE_NAMES it seems like we want to set it to 'Europe/London' as Oracle can use this to determine if and what needs to be  changed automatically for daylight savings.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

- `SYSTIMESTAMP` is returned in the time zone of database server's operating system.
- Usually you should provide time zone in `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ()`, however if you don't specify then Oracle uses the `SESSIONTIMEZONE`. You can set session time zone with command:

  `ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE= ...;`
- Default time zone for SQL session can be set by Environment variable `ORA_SDTZ`. In Windows you can also set Registry Key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Oracle\KEY_{Oracle Home Name}\ORA_SDTZ`

Actually you cannot control the **session** time zone from server side. The server may provide a default time zone, however such default apply only if value is not set in client.

Comment: Thanks for the info Wernfried, the alter session is something we have considered. Mostly this would be inside pl/sql blocks so we know it would have to be wrapped in execute immediate.
I do not think any session fix would be appropriate given the nature of who could be running these scripts.

Currently the only work around I have would be to run the likes of:
SELECT to_timestamp_tz(systimestamp) at time zone 'Europe/London' from dual; and use that for the insert statement.

Comment: Simply use `SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London'` - that's sufficient as value of `SYSTIMESTAMP` is a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type.